# How to replace string of arbitrary semi-repeating characters (Python)

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

How would one go about finding/replacing the following string:
"< some_string> S< char 1>S< char 2>-S< char 2>S< char 1>< some string 2>"?

Here we use the notation < char> as some arbitrary character. For instance I might want to replace "aSxSy-SySxb" with "aCOMb". I have read up on groups, but this method does not seem to do the trick, for instance I tried:

```
import re

s = re.sub("S(.=\1)S(.=\2)+S\2S\1","SxSx+SySx","COM")
print(s)
```

which I though would print s as:

```
>>> SxSx+SySx
```

since it doesn't match as far as I understand groups, but it prints:

```
>>> Com
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: `"COM"` is the input. Since there is no match, you get COM as output.

Comment: You mean this ? `s = re.sub("S(.)S(.)S\2S\1","COM", "SxSx+SySx",)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I this specific example I expect it to return the string unchanged, since x!=y I would assume \1!=\2. I interpreted these as group names. 

Unfortunately you solution doesn't make the replacement when it should, i.e.
    
    **s = re.sub("S(.)S(.)+S\2S\1","COM", "SxSy+SySx")
    print(s)**

Should yield
    **>>> COM**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It goes re.sub(pattern_to_look_for, value_to_replace_pattern_with, string_input)

Comment: @JanCilliéLouw Sure, and look at your code. This is exactly why you get `COM` as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backreferences.

To match the pattern you describe, try the following:

```
import re
s = "abcSxSy-SySxdef"
m = re.match(".*S(?P<char1>.)S(?P<char2>.)-S(?P=char2)S(?P=char1).*", s)
print(m.group(0))  # Prints "abcSxSy-SySxdef"
print(m.groups())  # Prints "('x', 'y')"
```

Replacing the pattern is similar, but of course it depends what you want to replace. For example, to replace all occurrences of `char2` with 'T',

```
print(re.sub(
    "(.*S)(?P<char1>.)S(?P<char2>.)-S(?P=char2)S(?P=char1)(.*)", 
    "\g<1>\g<2>ST-STS\g<2>\g<4>", s))  # Prints "abcSxST-STSxdef".
```

Specifically, you wanted to replace "aSxSy-SySxb" such that you end up with "xCOMb". Here is one way to do it:

```
print(re.sub(
    "(.*S)(?P<char1>.)S(?P<char2>.)-S(?P=char2)S(?P=char1)(.*)",
    "\g<2>COM\g<4>",
    "aSxSy-SySxb"))  # Prints "xCOMb"
```